# Is MKS Integrity stream-based?

Tags: continuous-integration, mks

The book Continuous Delivery discusses stream-based VCS and I'm having to use MKS now so was wondering if MKS is of that category. Thanks

In the book it discusses IBM ClearCase as an example of stream-based VCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **YES** it is.

If you disagree please let me know.